# Is there any definition of the sum of $n$ summands, when $n$ is not a natural number?

Tags: calculus, summation, fractional-iteration

I think, from the algebraic point of view, that this doesn't make sense, since the addition of $n$ terms is defined "inductively" from the binary operation of the addition. This even yields the formula of $nx = x + x + \cdots + x$, where the $x$ is added $n$ times (which I saw as a different operation than the multiplication in a ring, but an action of the natural numbers in the ring).

However, it would make sense to make a definition of adding $n \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ terms or summands? Something like the sense of a fractional derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markus Muller and Dierk Schleicher say there is.

http://www.mpmueller.net/HowToAdd.pdf

Comment: I love that people took the time to make sense of something so seemingly nonsensical!

Comment: Amazing. It's surprising that there's not many articles about those kind of definitions. Another article I found (same authors) can be found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502109